# how to analyze salesforce profiles, roles and permission set?

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, roles

An org with 600+ users, 500+ roles and 70 profiles. my job is clean up the role and profile in system manner. to be specific, I need to analyze each profile and role to understand and compare similar profiles, find the differences. In order to combine roles and reduce number of profiles. or introduce permission set if necessary.

I have exported all the roles and profiles comparing using excel. but it's almost impossible to do as there are so many columns. even break down to groups does not help much.

my question is: can anyone give me some advise on what approach is efficient and proper to find out all the differences between two profiles? (down to fields on each object)

Comment: I understand the clean up part, there is any other reason to do. I will recommend to establish a clear administration process so this can be tracked and maintained well. Otherwise I m afraid you possibly will be here again with same situation.

Comment: Hi Nazeer, you are absolutely right, I am taking over the admin job now. and once I clean it up, I will definitely keep it well documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Salesforce PermComparator](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/) might be the exact tool you need. You can enter in a user, profile, or permission set and compare it to any other.

Roles are a little bit more difficult, as they don't actually have any permissions directly associated with them, they just control sharing. You're going to need to evaluate the sharing criteria on every object that has an OWD of private to figure out exactly how your hierarchy is and is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 0):

might also try the salesforce optimizer report. I believe it's just a built-in report. Go to setup, then type in "Salesforce Optimizer" and I believe you should be able to find it. **https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=optimizer_kick_off.htm&type=5**